# How to get list of users from LDAP directory using PHP?

Tags: php, ldap

```
$ldaphost = "my_host_name";
$ds=ldap_connect($ldaphost) or die("Could not connect to $ldaphost"); 
ldap_set_option ($ds, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
ldap_set_option ($ds, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);

if ($ds) 
{ 
    $basedn = 'my_dc_string';
    $samaccountname = 'my_user_name';
    $filters = "(samaccountname={$samaccountname})";
    $result = ldap_search($ds, $basedn, $filters);
}
```

How do I get the list of all users from LDAP using PHP? The above code fails on the ldap_search function giving this warning

"Warning: ldap_search(): Search: Operations error"

my username, ldaphost etc are correct.  I am not sure about the filters though.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
/**
 * Get a list of users from Active Directory.
 */
$ldap_password = 'PASSWORD';
$ldap_username = 'USERNAME@DOMAIN';
$ldap_connection = ldap_connect(HOSTNAME);
if (FALSE === $ldap_connection){
    // Uh-oh, something is wrong...
}

// We have to set this option for the version of Active Directory we are using.
ldap_set_option($ldap_connection, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3) or die('Unable to set LDAP protocol version');
ldap_set_option($ldap_connection, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0); // We need this for doing an LDAP search.

if (TRUE === ldap_bind($ldap_connection, $ldap_username, $ldap_password)){
    $ldap_base_dn = 'DC=XXXX,DC=XXXX';
    $search_filter = '(&(objectCategory=person)(samaccountname=*))';
    $attributes = array();
    $attributes[] = 'givenname';
    $attributes[] = 'mail';
    $attributes[] = 'samaccountname';
    $attributes[] = 'sn';
    $result = ldap_search($ldap_connection, $ldap_base_dn, $search_filter, $attributes);
    if (FALSE !== $result){
        $entries = ldap_get_entries($ldap_connection, $result);
        for ($x=0; $x<$entries['count']; $x++){
            if (!empty($entries[$x]['givenname'][0]) &&
                 !empty($entries[$x]['mail'][0]) &&
                 !empty($entries[$x]['samaccountname'][0]) &&
                 !empty($entries[$x]['sn'][0]) &&
                 'Shop' !== $entries[$x]['sn'][0] &&
                 'Account' !== $entries[$x]['sn'][0]){
                $ad_users[strtoupper(trim($entries[$x]['samaccountname'][0]))] = array('email' => strtolower(trim($entries[$x]['mail'][0])),'first_name' => trim($entries[$x]['givenname'][0]),'last_name' => trim($entries[$x]['sn'][0]));
            }
        }
    }
    ldap_unbind($ldap_connection); // Clean up after ourselves.
}

$message .= "Retrieved ". count($ad_users) ." Active Directory users\n";
```

Comment: This works...except the result set is empty, looking into it.  Thank you

Comment: Awesome.  Got it working.  Now off to get all the info for all the users

Answer (score 1):

From [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/ldap.using.php):

```
ldap_connect()    // establish connection to server
   |
ldap_bind()       // anonymous or authenticated "login"
   |
do something like search or update the directory
and display the results
   |
ldap_close()      // "logout"
```

You should use `ldap_bind()` to login & after all operartion(s) `ldap_close()` to close the connection.

[Example usage here.](http://php.net/manual/en/ldap.examples-basic.php)